# ng-repeat not showing information

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Why is the ng-repeat not working with the given data? I know it has something to do with the view loaded before the data or something. But I fill the selectedCourses array based on the users input, and the view shows that the Array is populated, but the ng-repeat div DOES NOTHING! please help.

```
<br />
  Matches {{ matches }}

  <br />
  hits {{ hits }}

  <br />
  selected Courses: {{selectedCourses}} 
  <br />

  <div ng-repeat = "selCourse in selectedCourses" >
    <h3> {{selCourse}}  </h3>
  </div>

<br />
<label class="control-label">Search Class to Add </label>
 <input placeholder = "Enter a class" ng-model = "courseInput" type="text" class="form-control" id="courseInput">
```

So the HTML should be repeating the information in the selectedCourses array as h3 headers, but it show nothing! 
[Check out this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VTbh.png)

Do I need to do something to reload the ng-repeat section of the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have the duplicate in your array("ENGR 170 (31237)" as i see on the picture), try to use `track by $index`

`ng-repeat="selCourse in selectedCourses track by $index"`